# debugger detaching when using intent

Tags: android, debugging, android-intent, intellij-idea

I'm doing some prototyping in Android (using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1) against another app's intent API. The problem I'm running into is that after I'm finished with the task in the second app and I'm returned back to my prototype, half the time the debugger detaches and I need to start all over. It's extremely frustrating and really dragging down my productivity.

Are there any tips to minimize this from happening? The one thing I've found is to have the log level in the debugger set to Error.

thanks!

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint at the very start of your `onActivityResult()` method?

Comment: The intent calls are wrapped in an API. I'll see if I can hook into that somehow. Good tip, thanks!